# Rebuild project without stopping debugging

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I have a Visual C++ solution which includes a StartUp project and many DLL projects which are dynamically loaded and unloaded by the StartUp project. I'd like to rebuild a DLL project without stopping the current debugging session. However trying this will prompt me with the "Do you want to stop debugging?" popup.

Manually running msbuild on the project will fail with:

```
"D:\MySolution\MyDLLProject\dllproject.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
(Link target) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1201: error writing to program database 'D:\MySolution\compiled\DebugDB\MyDLLProject\Debug\dllproject.pdb'; check for insufficient disk space, invalid path, or insufficient privilege [D:\MySolution\MyDLLProject\dllproject.vcxproj]
```

Is there a way to circumvent this?

Comment: I don't know if it will work for DLLs, but have you tried to [enable "Edit and continue"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yty6a48.aspx)?

Comment: Yes, i've enabled it. However does not help with rebuilding.

Comment: This approach works well outside of Visual Studio with msbuild, has anyone found a way to convince the IDE to allow rebuilding a DLL while debugging is in progress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to make sure is that the pdb file which gets generated by your new build of the dll is not the same as with the last build.

Using the command line to build the dlls you could invoke the compiler/linker 
with a command line switch -PDB:>>PDBFILENAME_%random%.pdb<<

This will create a pdb file which is different everytime you recompile.

Example:
**cl main.cpp -LD /link -PDB:test_%random%.pdb**

Comment: Will this enable me to debug the new dll?

Comment: yes i just did a small test to confirm this. if you build a new pdb file and make sure that this file is completley written by the time you try to load the dll then the debugger will load the symbols for the newly build pdb file

Comment: Just confirmed with my original project that this works. Wonderful, thank you. Only burden seems to be the cleanup of pdb files as they range towards 10s of MBs. I'll solve that with automation.

Answer (score 2):

The reason of the error is that the `pdb` files are currently in use by your MSVC-debugger. While building your project in debug mode this files are need to be overwritten but this is impossible since you can't delete the file that is currently in use.

> A program database (PDB) file holds debugging and project state information that allows incremental linking of a Debug configuration of your program. It also stores the debug information.

So if you'll build your project without `pdb` files you'll be able to build it while debugging. But in this case, since your pdb-files would be outdated you are unable to debug your application. That means, that to rebuild your project and be able to debug it after you ought to stop your debugger session. Or, as a doubtful solution, you may build it into another directory to avoid pdb-file write conflicts.

Comment: That makes sense. Is there any way to unload the database and reload the symbols?

Comment: @Tom pdb files are loaded automatically by the debugger -> debugger can't work without pdb files, which means that unloading pdb files is an synonym of stopping debug session.

Comment: That's unfortunate, i guess this is beyond my scope. I wonder if there are any technical limitations for not being able to hotswitch pdb files?

Comment: @Tom Potentially the problem can be solved, but it may cause another problems. See: actually the pdb-files can be loaded into ram after what they can be deleted. But, in case of large projects, the pdb files may have huge size and they can not be loaded into RAM. That's why, I guess, debugger just reads it from the HDD, and that makes the files ought to be unchanged. But, if your `hotswitch` means loading different pdb-files, you better ask microsoft developers about that.

Comment: See answer below by H. Kretzschmar. Not sure if there are any corner cases where it could fail though. It's not a perfect solution, but works!

Comment: @Tom Haha, well, nice! Glad you solved your problem. As for me, I don't use visual studio for years, so I did not know that it is even possible :)

Answer (score 1):

There´s built in mechanism inside VS to alow this to happen.

(Just tested with a C# MVC project)

Instead to compile with (F5), use (Ctrl + F5). 
This will compile your solution with no debugger attached to the browser.

Do not close the bowser tab and Get back to Visual studio. Change anything inside a controller or a class. 
You will see that Visual Studio works smooth like when the solution it´s stop.

Now, press (Ctrl + Shft + B) to call the build mechanism. This will generate all new dlls

Switch to the browser again and refresh the page (F5 or Ctrl + r)

This is a time saver!

**In summary**

1. VS: Ctrl + F5
2. chrome: renders the page
3. VS: Change anythng  Ctrl + Shift + B
4. chrome: Ctrl + r